# What are the differences between the 'data.frame', 'tribble' and 'tibble' functions?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, tibble

What are the differences between the `data.frame`, `tribble`, and `tibble` functions? Which is easier and which is more useful for analyzing lots of data? I'm creating a data frame and I don't know which one to choose.

Answer (score 6):

## Data frames

A [data frame](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/data.frame) is a table, where each column can have different types of values. Its purpose is similar to spreadsheets, or SQL tables. An example can make things clearer.

### Example

Suppose, for example, you have data about people: name, age, and whether they are employed. We can have these data in vectors, for example:

```
names <- c('John', 'Sylvia', 'Arthemis')
age <- c(32, 16, 21)
employed <- c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
```

A data frame allows us to have all the data related to a person in one row. To create it, we just pass the vectors as arguments to `data.frame()`:

```
> df <- data.frame(Name=names, Age=age, Working=employed)
> df
      Name Age Working
1     John  32    TRUE
2   Sylvia  16   FALSE
3 Arthemis  21    TRUE
```

Note how clearer the data format is now. With data frames, many operations become easier. For example, filtering:

```
> df[df$Age>20,]
      Name Age Working
1     John  32    TRUE
3 Arthemis  21    TRUE
```

This is just one example of many. Filtering, aggregating, plotting, etc. became much more straightforward with data frames.

## Tibbles

[Tibbles](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/) are just a new kind of data frame. It is part of the very popular [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) set of packages and subtly differs from data frames in a few points.

### Differences from data frames

One notable difference is that the tibble format contains more information:

```
> t <- tibble(Name=names, Age=age, Working=employed)
> t
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name       Age Working
  <chr>    <dbl> <lgl>  
1 John        32 TRUE   
2 Sylvia      16 FALSE  
3 Arthemis    21 TRUE
```

More important, though, is that tibbles do not have some confusing features that data frames have.

For example, you can get a column from the data frame by giving only the beginning of the column name:

```
> df$N
[1] "John"     "Sylvia"   "Arthemis"
```

It may look practical, but if you find this line in your source code, it can be hard to understand. It can also lead to bugs if multiple columns start with the same prefix.

If you do that to tibbles, it will return `NULL` and print a warning:

```
> t$N
NULL
Warning message:
Unknown or uninitialised column: `N`.
```

This is just one example. More differences can be found [on this page](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/articles/tibble.html#tibbles-vs-data-frames), although most of them are more relevant to older, more experienced coders.

## The `tribble()` function

We created tibble objects with the function `tibble()` so far. `tribble()` is just another way of creating tibble objects. The difference is that, while `tibble()` receives vectors very much like `data.frame()`, `tribble()` expects as arguments:

- the name of the columns in the so-called "tilde syntax"; and then
- each row

without having to create any vector.

### How to use `tribble()`

To understand what it means and why it is useful, an example will make it clear:

```
> t2 <- tribble(
+   ~Name,       ~Age, ~`Employment status`,
+   "John",      32,   TRUE,
+   "Sylvia",    16,   FALSE,
+   "Arthemis",  21,   TRUE
+ )
```

Note that you can see the table format when inputting the data. It is great for examples in code! But don't be mistaken: the return object is equivalent to the same thing created by `tibble()`:

```
> t2
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  Name       Age `Employment status`
  <chr>    <dbl> <lgl>              
1 John        32 TRUE               
2 Sylvia      16 FALSE              
3 Arthemis    21 TRUE
```

## Which one to use?

You can use whatever you prefer! All of them work well. Yet some can be more fit to one context or another.

- If you are not using tidyverse, you'd probably use traditional data frames.
- Now, if you are using tidyverse, you'd probably prefer tibbles, since they are a cornerstone of those packages. You may also prefer tibble to avoid confusing data frame behaviors.

Supposing you're going to create tibbles, which function should you use?

- If you are reading data from files, or from vectors, you will probably prefer to use `tibble()`.
- If you are going to add hardcoded values to your tibble, then the `tribble()` function may be more practical.

## Addendum: mixing `tibble()` and `tribble()` up

`tibble()` and `tribble()` return the same kind of object, but they have very different signatures. Yet, their names are really similar, so people often confuse them. Pay attention to that!

If you call `tibble()` passing `tribble()` arguments, you'll get an error similar to this:

```
# ❌ WRONG!
> tibble(
+ ~Name, ~Age, ~`Employment status`,
+ "John", 32, TRUE
+ )
Error:
! All columns in a tibble must be vectors.
✖ Column `~Name` is a `formula` object.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If you call `tribble()` passing `tibble()` arguments, this is the error you will get:

```
# ❌ WRONG!
> t <- tribble(Name=names, Age=age, Working=employed)
Error:
! Must specify at least one column using the `~name` syntax.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

If you are having problems with error messages similar to those ones, verify you're using the right signature in your call.

*(I'm posting this addendum so people googling for these errors can find this Q&A. I spent an hour trying to understand why I was getting that error. This is a surprisingly ungoogleable topic!)*